# Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My application is using a lot of webviews which are lying in fragments which are hold by a ViewPager.

Whenever i swipe through the app on my Galaxy Nexus with Jellybean on it i get the following console message again and again:

```
08-23 13:44:03.374: E/webcoreglue(21690): Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong here so that i might be able to fix the issue?

Comment: By "a lot" means roughly how many WebViews? >256? >1024? I'm just curious.

Comment: About 40 tops! 1 for each Fragment.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364971/jelly-bean-webview-app-does-not-respond-to-touchend-events-perfectly/15014386#15014386

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue occurs because in some scenarios WebView fails to notice that its visible rect has changed, so as far as webkit is concerned the page is still not visible. Thus all touches fall outside of the window, and get rejected.

The cleanest fix is when you know the visibility of your WebView has changed (such as in response to a setPrimaryItem callback from a viewpager), call `webview.onScrollChanged(webview.getScrollX(), webview.getScrollY());`

You will need to subclass the webview to promote the protected onScrollChanged to a public method.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation and cleanest solution, should be the top answer.

Comment: This answer put me on the right track. I added `public void applyAfterMoveFix()
        {
        onScrollChanged(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), getScrollX(), getScrollY());
        }` to my webview subclass.

Answer (score 18):

I had this exact issue.  The problem is exactly what Rahul Dole said in his answer above.

I spend a few days on this trying tons of different things.  I noticed that when the orientation changed that the visible WebView onLongClick worked again...so I came up with this little gem.  Indeed its very hacky but it works!

**Use this in your class that extends WebView:**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        int temp_ScrollY = getScrollY();
        scrollTo(getScrollX(), getScrollY() + 1);
        scrollTo(getScrollX(), temp_ScrollY);

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: You can get the same effect by calling onScrollChanged() directly.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

I faced exactly the same problem. In my app wherever i had click events coded using 'touchend' in jquery bind(), this error was coming up and it used to never respond to clicks (taps).. and gave a frozen kind of feel.
So I just tried replacing 'touchend' with 'click' in bind(), and it worked! responded to clicks (Taps) and also didn't show that log entry of webcoreglue..

I also found this piece of code in Android's webview code..

```
HTMLElement* WebViewCore::retrieveElement(int x, int y,
    const QualifiedName& tagName)
{
    HitTestResult hitTestResult = m_mainFrame->eventHandler()
        ->hitTestResultAtPoint(IntPoint(x, y), false, false,
        DontHitTestScrollbars, HitTestRequest::Active | HitTestRequest::ReadOnly,
        IntSize(1, 1));
    if (!hitTestResult.innerNode() || !hitTestResult.innerNode()->inDocument()) {
        LOGE("Should not happen: no in document Node found");
        return 0;
    }
    const ListHashSet<RefPtr<Node> >& list = hitTestResult.rectBasedTestResult();
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        LOGE("Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found");
        return 0;
    }
    Node* node = hitTestResult.innerNode();
    Node* element = node;
    while (element && (!element->isElementNode()
        || !element->hasTagName(tagName))) {
        element = element->parentNode();
    }
    DBG_NAV_LOGD("node=%p element=%p x=%d y=%d nodeName=%s tagName=%s", node,
        element, x, y, node->nodeName().utf8().data(),
        element ? ((Element*) element)->tagName().utf8().data() : "<none>");
    return static_cast<WebCore::HTMLElement*>(element);
}​
```

and this too..

```
// get the highlight rectangles for the touch point (x, y) with the slop
Vector<IntRect> WebViewCore::getTouchHighlightRects(int x, int y, int slop)
{
    Vector<IntRect> rects;
    m_mousePos = IntPoint(x - m_scrollOffsetX, y - m_scrollOffsetY);
    HitTestResult hitTestResult = m_mainFrame->eventHandler()->hitTestResultAtPoint(IntPoint(x, y),
            false, false, DontHitTestScrollbars, HitTestRequest::Active | HitTestRequest::ReadOnly, IntSize(slop, slop));
    if (!hitTestResult.innerNode() || !hitTestResult.innerNode()->inDocument()) {
        LOGE("Should not happen: no in document Node found");
        return rects;
    }
    const ListHashSet<RefPtr<Node> >& list = hitTestResult.rectBasedTestResult();
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        LOGE("Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found");
        return rects;
    }
//Rest of the part is omitted here...
```

Notice that log message there? I am guessing this code is for identifying the x and y axis vectors generated on clicks or taps or swipes..
    ​

Comment: I dont use make use of jquery´s bind. But notherless your answer might give some direction where the problem might be. In fact i use Zepto instead of Jquery but also no Zepto bind´s.

Comment: Are you doing `webView.destroy()` in the `onDestroy()` function in main.java file?

Comment: No i dont, i dont use the destroy method of webview.

Comment: try it, might help. probably all the webviews.

Comment: I put the webview.destroy() into the fragments onDestroy() unfortunaly with no success. But the problem could be related to the lifecycle. as i swipe through the pager the message occurs. I use a fragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: Thats close enough for me! Thanks!

Comment: The use of the click event is not really perfect as it has a delay of 400ms compared to the touchend event. Do you guys know if it's a bug in Android or us who are doing something wrong ???

Comment: to me it looks like a bug in android apparently, or maybe they have made some change and didn't declare it in change log. Not sure.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this answer either, using click instead of touchend introduces a delay and makes the app seem slow...

Comment: I met with John Reck, an engineer on the Android WebView team, a couple of days ago. He confirmed that this is a bug--basically a race condition where the webkit layout engine gets out of sync with the Android layout and starts mapping touch events to an incorrect coordinate system. Until the bug is fixed, calling onScrollChanged() to resync the layouts seems to be the best workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem with JellyBean and ViewPager + fragments that contains WebViews. And all OK with the same code running on Android 2.2, so I think this is a bug in JB WebView implementation.

On JB only the first shown fragment with WebView works right, without errors "Should not happen .." in the log, and getHitTestResult() calls returns correct values. Swiping to the next pages, I got errors in log and getHitTestResult() returns only zeroes and nulls.

Now I found only one solution to create fragments with empty containers and create WebViews, setup they and load data only when current fragment becomes active in the ViewPager. In this case WebView works as needed. But, unfortunately, this completely breaks an idea of smooth swiping pages in the ViewPager.

Have the last idea, tomorrow will try to replace ViewPager's fragments to compound views. Little chances, but I'll let you know if results will be successful.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer! As I wrote earlier, I found only one workaround to create WebView when current fragment becomes active in the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a clue why it worked. I added onTouchEvent listener into my MainActivity.java to fix this issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public class MyWebView extends WebView {

          public MyWebView(Context context) {
            super(context);
      }

      public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        onScrollChanged(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), getScrollX(), getScrollY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me when I was working in Cordova + Sencha Touch environment. Because
`CordovaActivity` does not have anything like `onScrollChanged()` method I could not apply any of the above solutions.

After hours of banging my head against the wall I discovered that some parts of web interface had been called before this was completely rendered. In my case those methods were triggered by `activate` event in `Ext.PanelView`. I replaced that event with `painted` and since then everything works like a charm.

Although it is not copy-paste solution I hope it may help someone to save time on investigation.

Answer (score 0):

**Another solution:**

You don't need to extend the WebView class to fix that.. I've got that fixed by adding the following two lines right after loading the web view content (myWebView.loadUrl("..."):

```
wv.loadUrl("your url here");

//Add the following two lines
myWebView.scrollTo(myWebView.getScrollX(), myWebView.getScrollY()+1);
myWebView.scrollTo(myWebView.getScrollX(), myWebView.getScrollY()-1);
```

Hope this will help (I tested myself and it worked).

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Even I have WebView inside a ViewPager, and fixed this problem by overriding `onTouchEvent()` by extending webview class.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {       
            requestFocusFromTouch();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Cheers !!!