# Android web view error

Tags: android

I know its been asked several times. I got the error "Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found" when loading the url onto web view .I searched many time and i saw the link given below. [Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090899/android-webview-jellybean-should-not-happen-no-rect-based-test-nodes-found) . But i can't understand the solution they provided.  plz help me.

```
try
{
    wv[tmpm].getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv[tmpm].setWebViewClient(new Myweb());
    //wv[tmpm].setWebViewClient(new Myweb);
    //wv[tmpm].loadUrl(url);
}
```

Myweb class given below

```
private class Myweb extends WebViewClient
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("In extends webview client","HIiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;};
    }
}
```

Comment: `return true;` should be used at `MyWeb`

Comment: yeh.. i used return true but not working..

Comment: my web views (wv[tmpm]) are programatically created web views

Comment: also my webview client not calling..... the log not shown in log cat

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364971/jelly-bean-webview-app-does-not-respond-to-touchend-events-perfectly/15014386#15014386

Comment: This appears to be the same as what is described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42518#c12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding @Override above your boolean method in Myweb

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d("In extends webview client","HIiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;};
}
```