# Android WebView in different Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, webview, swipe

I'm working on a project with "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager". There are 2 tabs and in each of these tabs I want to show a different WebView. Here is the code of one of those tabs and it's layout :

**TabOne.java**

```
public class TabOne extends Fragment
{
 WebView myWebView;
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabone, container, false);
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help/index.html");
    return view;
}
}
```

**tabone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that in the first tab, the WebView is loaded corectly. On the other Tab, which is exactly the same declared, I can't focus elements and I am getting some Force Closes sometimes. If I'm on the second tab, which has the error, and I switch the orientation to Landscape, the second tab is loaded perfectly but when I switch to the first tab I get the error. Here is the LogCat error :

```
11-18 09:00:37.460: E/webcoreglue(29444): Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
```

Comment: The override of onActivityCreated is useless, you just call super..

Comment: i dont think, the log you have posted is related to crash, post the log below Fatal exception

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A2Evqxyk : Here is the full log. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [a bug, either in `ViewPager` or `WebView`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42518), on Android 4.1 (and perhaps higher).

Alas, I have no workaround for having `WebView` be on the second or subsequent pages of the pager.

Comment: @IamDeveloper: No. Worse, it appears that the `WebView`-in-the-first-page solution does not work reliably either.

Comment: This is a bug as @CommonsWare links above.  Here is a solution I found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15153292/468360

Answer (score 0):

In Java, create **MyWebView** as **sub class** of **WebView**

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        onScrollChanged(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), getScrollX(), getScrollY());
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

In layout xml, using **MyWebView** *instead of* **WebView**

```
<your.package.MyWebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have `WebView` inside a `ViewPager` and fixed this problem by overriding `onTouchEvent()` by extending `WebView` class.

Here is my code:

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
requestFocusFromTouch(); } return super.onTouchEvent(event); }
```

Cheers!