# how to edit error Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Hi I receive the below error (html5, jquery app)

```
Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
```

after the below code executed

```
$('#submit').unbind('click').click(function(){ code }
```

The error occurs on every touch after the click on the above button...

I cannot find out what fires up this error.

How can I fix this?

I follow this [Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090899/android-webview-jellybean-should-not-happen-no-rect-based-test-nodes-found) but I cannot understand what to do...

Comment: This appears to be the same as what is described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42518#c12

Answer (score 1):

Disallow over-scroll in your app by adding following preference in your config.xml file under preferences

preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true"