# WebView in ViewPager not receive user inputs

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I am implementing a ViewPager with webviews inside it.
The webviews contains javascripts to interact with the user.

The webview on the first page work, while the others do not work.

If a webview is higher then the screen, after I scroll it down or up, then it works.
I think it is like the webview showed firstly maintain the "focus" and not let the others to get the events.

I cannot a solution to it,
all the webview work if I set them as the first page, but they do not work in the following pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After a lot of headache, I find this is the same problem as showed here:
[Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090899/android-webview-jellybean-should-not-happen-no-rect-based-test-nodes-found)

I solved it by subclassing WebView and overriding the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    webview.onScrollChanged(webview.getScrollX(), webview.getScrollY());
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Probably the first webview showed is correctly created while the other which are created by the viewpager in background, have a wrong area for receiving the event.

Maybe there is a better way to solve it, but at least now it works.