# webcoreglue Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found Android 4.3

Tags: android, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

i'm developing an android app using a WebView that shows a grid where you can add value by a long touch in the grid. But every time i touch the webView, there's this error that keeps popping in the logcat.

> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found

I've tried all the fixes that i found here : [Android WebView JellyBean -> Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090899/android-webview-jellybean-should-not-happen-no-rect-based-test-nodes-found) But none of them works for me.

I am using a Dell Venue 7 3730 v.4.3 .

I also have an Nexus 7 v4.4.2, where it works perfectlty, the error doesn't exist.

If you have any idea how to fix the bug, or where does it come from ?

Thank you.